# how can i solve porblem with ngstyle?

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-style

```
    <div [ngStyle]="{
  width:'200px',
  height:'200px',
  border:'1px solid red'
}"
```

this is code which i wrote ate post.component.html
there is error:Unexpected character "EOF" (

what's wrong?

Comment: please add full code.

Comment: this is full code

Comment: Please rephrase the question, make it clearer and grammatically right.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `</div>`

`<div [ngStyle]="{ width:'200px', height:'200px', border:'1px solid red' }"></div>`